# I'm having trouble finding example code for libftdi's mpsse (SPI) mode

Tags: c, usb, libusb

This is not a homework problem, though it is a work problem. Where months ago, I would have just written up a specification and the boss would have contracted it out, money's tight. So I'm trying to do this myself.

I'm a weak C coder, and I'm lucky if gcc spits out something that will run without segfaulting, or sometimes anything at all. Still, I manage. Libftdi is built, I've carefuly perused both its example executables/code, and the documentation. But I'm still lost.

Does anyone know of a software project that makes use of its MPSEE mode, that's hooked into an SPI device? Is anyone here slick enough to provide an example? I could really use the help. I don't need this handed to me on a silver platter, but I'm having trouble even getting started. If I could even figure out how to initialize it and send a byte to the chip on the other side of the FTDI ic, I think I might manage to muddle my way through it.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flashrom can use FT2232 SPI mode: http://flashrom.org/Downloads

Comment: Thank you, I've been using it and now have some success. I'd recommend it if anyone else is trying to do SPI with an FT chip. Now if I could just find a bitbang example...

Comment: IMO, this link would be more precise: https://github.com/flashrom/flashrom/blob/master/ft2232_spi.c .

Comment: Good point, but that repo did not exist yet in 2010 when I wrote that answer.